# Docker run -m doesnt set the limit (JVM takes up the entire host machine's size for xms and xmx)

Tags: java, docker, memory, jvm, limit

I have a server with 16GB RAM. I am trying to set the memory limit to the container by running

```
docker run -it -m 500M <image-name>
```

On the docker stats, it shows the container has the memory limit of 500MB. But when i try to do

```
docker exec -it <containerID> /bin/sh
```

and do a "top", it shows the available memory as 16GB..

Should it not be set to 500MB ?

The main reason why i need it to be 500 MB is I have java application running in each container. And by default the JVM takes 16gb/64 as the Xms and 4gb as Xmx.
:(

Comment: What's the output of `docker stats` for that container?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096632/limit-memory-on-a-docker-container-doesnt-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: One of the key features of Java 10 is better co-operation with Docker.  You might want to look at Java 10. https://www.opsian.com/blog/java-on-docker/

Comment: @PeterLawrey . Yeah.. I am using Java 10 with experimental features turned on. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this article will help you to understand why free and top doesn't work correctly inside containers.

```
Most of the Linux tools providing system resource metrics were created before 
cgroups even existed (e.g.: free and top, both from procps). They usually read 
memory metrics from the proc filesystem: /proc/meminfo, /proc/vmstat, 
/proc/PID/smaps and others.

Unfortunately /proc/meminfo, /proc/vmstat and friends are not containerized. 
Meaning that they are not cgroup-aware. They will always display memory 
numbers from the host system (physical or virtual machine) as a whole, which 
is useless for modern Linux containers

This causes a lot of confusion for users of Linux containers. Why does free 
say there is 32GB free memory, when the container only allows 512MB to be 
used?
```

https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19485999)

Comment: Does this extract answer your question ?

Comment: @fly2matrix .. Yeah.. Your answer and JDK 10 has solved the prob.. Thanks. Cheers :)