# Docker memory limits no taking effect for Java Apps in Centos 7 host

Tags: java, docker, centos7

I am trying to deploy several Java (spring boot) apps in docker containers in 1 host, where I set memory limits `(--memory=30m --memory-swap=50m)` for each.

However when I check the limits using docker container stats, I see each container is using  `>400MB` of the host's RAM. Due to this I cannot start all the containers I need as the kernel kills some of them (`OOM`).

What do I need to do to ensure that the containers' memory is controlled using the docker memory options?

My host is a digital ocean centos 7. Thanks

Comment: Does it report `WARNING: No swap limit support` at the end if you do `docker info`?

Comment: @lagom nope! no warnings

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for this issue is that JRE is not aware it is running inside a container.

**Let JVM detect how much memory is available in Docker container**
https://blog.csanchez.org/2017/05/31/running-a-jvm-in-a-container-without-getting-killed

> JAVA_OPTS="-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1"

Make sure you have JDK 8-131 or above version
In case of JDK-9 it will be available to correctly detect available memory inside container.

Additional Referece: [Docker run -m doesnt set the limit (JVM takes up the entire host machine's size for xms and xmx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919657/docker-run-m-doesnt-set-the-limit-jvm-takes-up-the-entire-host-machines-size)
and
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the JAVA_OPTS, should I put them in the Dockerfile or on the docker run command. Please a sample Dockerfile or docker run command if necessary

Comment: Use JAVA_OPTS as ENV in Dockerfile and Override if required while creating container from the image.

Comment: it is actually java 10 that introduce container awareness (as well as a useful flag to deal with it: `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage`). Try with: `docker run -m 1GB openjdk:10-jre java -XshowSettings:vm -version`